# React.js Tables showing key error in console

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I rendered a table of inventory a small business carries (stored in JSON file).

I get this error in my console:
**"Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
Check the render method of *`Table`***

My `App` returns `Table`

```html
  <Table wines={wines}/>
```

My `Table` component:

```html
import React from 'react'
import Row from './Row'
 
const Table = ({ wines,wine }) => {
  return (
    <div >
        <table >
            <tbody >
            {wines.map(wine =>(
                    <Row wine={wine}/>
                ))}

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Table
```

`Row` component:

```html
import React from 'react'
import Cell from './Cell'

const Row = ({ wine }) => {
  return (
   <tr>
       {Object.entries(wine).map(([key, value]) => {
           return (
               <Cell key={key} cellData={JSON.stringify(value)}/>
           )

        } ) }
   </tr>
  )
}

export default Row
```

`Cell` component:

```html
import React from 'react'

const Cell = ({cellData,wine}) => {
  return (
    <td >
        {cellData}
    </td>
  )
}

export default Cell
```

The table renders fine with the data, but I cannot understand why that error above still appears in the console. I am new to React and in the learning process. Thank you.

Comment: Keys are missing in the `Table` component. I suggest you read from the docs about keys: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: You missed the key `<Row wine={wine}/>`

Answer (score 0):

In your Table component, there is a `key` prop missing, eg:

```
{wines.map(wine =>(
   <Row key={wine} wine={wine}/>
))}
```

It's important that the key prop is something unique to the item being iterated, as this is used to ensure the correct items are being updated, in the case where the component has to be re-rendered.